# CircularImageView show only a half ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

In my Android app with kotlin, I want to display a user image in the middle AppBar.
The following code is For circular Image :

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="134dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/userprofil"
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="0"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewUserName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/app_bar_layout" />
```

I want a result like this :[image]

But, I get the following result :[image]
What should I change to get the result

Comment: It must be because of the app bar elevation. You can add elevation more than the app bar on your imageview

Comment: Show as more code of your layout. It looks like your image view is placed to be below AppBar

Comment: yes, thank you. I just add elevation and I get what I want

Comment: @Lina kindly accept the answer so that it can be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app bar by default has an elevation of 8 dp. So if you are adding any views overlapping with them without adding elevation then they will stay hidden behind the app bar. You need to add elevation more then 8dp on your imageview like below

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="134dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/userprofil"
        android:elevation="10dp" // Add this line
        app:civ_border="true"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="0"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewUserName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/app_bar_layout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put "translationZ" property in your imageview. so image view comes in front